# HTML video tag fixed height with object-fit

Tags: html, css

I need to put video inside parent div to match its (div's) dimensions. 
Specifically, I'm looking for full width and a fixed height.
Below code doesn't seem to be working.

HTML:

```
<div id="video-bg">
  <video autoplay muted loop>
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#video-bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

div#video-bg video {
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Codepen:

```
https://codepen.io/aartiik/pen/ErJRJK
```

Comment: Please verify the answer if it helped (Green check mark). Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The container `.bkg` is `display:flex` and `align-items: stretch` -- which makes its child tag (`.vid`) vertically stretch to the edge of the containing tag and comply with `max-height: 200px` (normally this is true *but* this particular layout is an exception, see footnotes<sup>1</sup>)
- The video is assigned `object-fit: cover` which sets the video edges to the edge of the container without distortion and if its Aspect Ratio doesn't fit within its containing tag, it will extend its edges past the container borders as needed. Also `object-position: center` is explicitly set.

  <sup><sup>1</sup>This particular layout has a side-effect in that it adds an extra 20px in height when video is assigned `object-fit: cover`. Therefore the height of `.bkg` is 180px as an offset. Setting `object-fit` to `fill` will fix that behavior.</sup>

---

### Demo

```css
:root {
  font: 400 16/1.3 Consolas;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bkg {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: center;
  max-height: 200px;
  height: 180px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.vid {
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bkg">
  <video class='vid' autoplay muted loop playsinline>
    <source src='https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
  </video>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't really need to keep aspect ratio 16:9. What I'm trying to achieve are full width (100%) and fixed height (e.g. 200px) video, thus object-fit:cover.

Comment: 100% width of what? The body? `object-fit:cover` will stretch edge to edge of body and you'll have only a clipped video.

Comment: 100% width of the div #video-bg and it's height(200px), clipped video is fine, I know it's impossible to do this without clipping.

Comment: @ArthurG Gotcha, this update displays video at 100% of container and the container stretches to 100% as well. The height is always 200px no matter the current width.

Comment: Amazing! Exactly what I needed! Thanks for the detailed explanation @zer00ne!

Answer (score 0):

add class to your video then style the video:

HTML:

```
<div id="video-bg">
  <video class="vid" autoplay muted loop>
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#video-bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

div#video-bg video {
  object-fit: cover;
}
.vid{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't working, as I mentioned I need a fixed height.

Comment: I edited the answer changing the object-fit to fill instead of cover and height: 100% please try again. thanks

Comment: Have you tried with object-fill? that + .vid class will make width: 100% and height 100% of the #video-bg which is 200px

Comment: That is better thanks, it fits the container now, but stretches video. It's not important if I lose parts of the video but it shouldn't be stretched. Here is codepen: https://codepen.io/aartiik/pen/WmgNmG

Comment: How you want it to be full width + 200px height with no strech? Is video being cut, fine for you? if yes then change object-fit to cover again. with same width: 100% height: 100%; I edited the answer

Comment: Yes, video being cut is fine. That is the exact problem, when I change to object-fit: cover, video gets out of the container.

Comment: No it doesnt. Go to codepen.io/aartiik/pen/WmgNmG and change it to cover you will see it doesnt overflow with the current css

Comment: Please check here: https://giphy.com/gifs/object-cover-5SAAaWyB6P5LIu3hdj